# App not in Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Quick question.

I have a few apps in the android market. They have all been in the market for about a year. Yesturday, I was in the Verizon store and decided to load all my apps on the phones in the store.

Well... I noticed that some of the newer phones didn't find my apps in a market search. Is there a setting I need to change in my apps to allow newer phones to find the apps?

I am running CyanogenMod7 2.3.3 and my phone finds all the apps.

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer phones should be able to see your apps, as long as they support all options that you have specified in the manifest.

Are you sure that they all supported your requirements? Android version, screen resolutions, sensors etc.

Regarding how screen resolutions have to do with it. From the documentation:

> Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application
>   supports
>
> By declaring which screen sizes your application supports, you can
>   ensure that only devices with the screens you support can download
>   your application. Declaring support for different screen sizes can
>   also affect how the system draws your application on larger
>   screens—specifically, whether your application runs in screen
>   compatibility mode. To declare the screen sizes your application
>   supports, you should include the  element in your
>   manifest file.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Edit. This is how you specify that you want to support multiple resolutions:

```
<supports-screens
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:xlargeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Yes. I think. I am not sure what screen resolution would have to do with it. My apps only need: Permissions: android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
Features: android.hardware.touchscreen

Comment: Ah....well it seems that if I specify a screen size, I would be cutting out all the others. Further, it seems that if I am only asking for the prev mentioned permissions, all phones should see the app in the market that have a touch screen.

Comment: No, you can specify that you support multiple resolutions. I'm updating my reply.